# \hspace underperforms in front of a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I found a problem in that an `\hspace` does not behave as I expected it to. I gave it -5em, but it only compiled about -4.5em. Changing the font family changes how much error there is, but I think the error within a font family is constant in terms of em units.

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes, 48pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=7cm, right=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\newlength\savetabcolsep\setlength\savetabcolsep\tabcolsep\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\newlength\leftitemspace\setlength\leftitemspace{5em}

Foo

\begin{tabular}{|p{\leftitemspace}|p{\linewidth}}
Foo & Bar\\
Foo 2 & Bar 2\\
Foo 3 & Bar3
\end{tabular}

\rule{1em}{1pt}

\hspace*{-\leftitemspace}      % here is the problem
\begin{tabular}{|p{\leftitemspace}|p{\linewidth}}
Foo & Bar\\
Foo 2 & Bar 2\\
\rule{\leftitemspace}{1pt} & Bar 3
\end{tabular}

\hspace{-\leftitemspace}\rule{\leftitemspace}{1pt}Bar


\setlength\tabcolsep\savetabcolsep
\end{document}
```

In the following picture, I'm trying to horizontally align the vertical lines of the table:

[image: hspace horizontal alignment problem]

Comment: In your calculations, have you included the space that you add between `\hspace*{...}` and `\begin{tabular}`? Have you made sure that there is no `\parindent`? Try adding a percent sign after `\hspace*{}`.

Comment: Btw, funny idea to call `\hspace` underperforming :-) So performance orientation has finally arrived in the world of LaTeX.

Comment: as @gernot showed the difference is simply the extra word space you had added, but why are you needing negative spaces at all? Is this just to compensate for paragraph indentation?

Comment: Related: [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\hspace*{-\leftitemspace}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Space removed
\begin{tabular}{|p{\leftitemspace}|p{\linewidth}}
```

[image]

Note that the lines in your sample file are not flush left, since each of them starts a new paragraph. If you want to let the stuff start at the left border of the text area, either add `\noindent` in each paragraphs or set `\parindent=0pt` for the whole document by adding it to the preamble.

```
\noindent
\hspace*{-\leftitemspace}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Space removed
\begin{tabular}{|p{\leftitemspace}|p{\linewidth}}
```

[image]

```
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
```

[image]

I recommend to add the option `showframe` to the `geometry` package while developing the document layout. Then text/header/footer/margin areas will be indicated.

```
\usepackage[left=7cm, right=0cm,showframe]{geometry}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah! Thanks! So a `␣` over the new line was to blame.